# what is the difference between echo %%~fF and echo %%~fF >> file.txt within recursive calls

Tags: file, batch-file, append, echo

i want to list subdirectories with a given level of nesting. console display works just fine, but while appending the same echo to a file it behaves different.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set currentLevel=0
set maxLevel=%1
if not defined maxLevel set maxLevel=1
 
:procFolder
pushd %1 2>nul
if %currentLevel% lss %maxLevel% (
  for /d %%F in (*) do (
    echo %%~fF
    echo %%~fF >> list.txt
    set /a currentLevel+=1
    call :procFolder "%%F"
    set /a currentLevel-=1
  )
)
popd
```

calling the batch-file with parameter 3 writes to the shell with the expected nesting of three subfolders

```
D:\erroronline1\code\learntoshell\sub1
D:\erroronline1\code\learntoshell\sub1\sub2
D:\erroronline1\code\learntoshell\sub1\sub2\sub3
```

but in the actual file there is just the first level of recursion written down

```
D:\erroronline1\code\learntoshell\sub1
```

this happens to all possible subfolders, just first level nesting is appended.
i could not control the level of nesting with other methods of listing subdirectories (for /r %%F in (.), dir /s) so this doesn't appear as an option.
pausing the recursion (to wait for the file being written, whatever) or passing the folder to a variable didn't help either.

what am i missing? what is possibly the difference between echo and echo >> file within a recursive call?

Comment: Do you know what arguments are, and how to use their assigned variables? I doubt very much that an expected number, to be assigned here `set maxLevel=%1`, will also be the name of a directory `pushd %1`. Also, are you really trying to call the section of your batch file, from within that same section?

Comment: Have you tried with `call :procFolder "%%~fF"`?

Comment: @Compo when i echo the variables maxLevel and currentLevel everything looks good, so i assume pushd %1 retrieves its argument from the call command having %%F passed as first argument.

Comment: @aschipfl yes, i tried that without effect

Comment: @erroronline1, not the first time it doesn't, it will try to change directory to `3`, and fail. Also as I already implied, it isn't a good idea to `call` a `:label` from from within a `for` loop which exists within that `:label` already.

Comment: @Compo i see that, but isn't the failing catched by 2>nul? and isn't calling itself the point of recursion? just being general curious.

Comment: Yes of course it is, but that wasn't the point I was making. My point was simply that your first two instances of `%1` were both for two completely different purposes

Comment: ah! hopefully having gotten it now. this was primarily untidy and confusing. if it was done in a clearer way there would be no need for 2>nul, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pushd changes the current directory.
The redirected echo output is appended to a file in the current directory.

Change the logfile from current directory to a full path and you will get all the logging in one file instead of several files in the nested directories.

Comment: It may make more sense, after `if not defined maxLevel set maxLevel=1`, to `Call :procFolder . 1> "list.txt"`, and the follow it with `GoTo :EOF`. Then simply change `echo %%~fF >> list.txt` to `Echo %%~fF 1> CON`.

Comment: @OJBakker omfg that makes sense! what have i done to all of the folders at work?!

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify things down to a two line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) by using the [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) utility:

Example: Run it by passing two arguments, the first being your directory, the second being your number of levels, e.g. test.cmd "%UserProfile%\Downloads" 3

```bsh
@Set /A Levels = %~2 + 1
@"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" "%~1" "%~1" /E /L /LEV:%LEVELS% /NC /NS /NFL /NJH /NJS 1> "list.txt"
```

And, if you really don't want the leading spaces:

```bsh
@Set /A Levels = %~2 + 1
@(For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe "%~1" "%~1" /E /L /LEV:%LEVELS% /NC /NS /NFL /NJH /NJS 2^> NUL') Do @Echo %%G) 1> "list.txt"
```

**[EDIT /]**

Based upon your comment, here's it modified for just a single argument, i.e. `test.cmd 3`, *(to use the current directory as the base)*.

```bsh
@Set /A Levels = %~1 + 1
@"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" . . /E /L /LEV:%LEVELS% /NC /NS /NFL /NJH /NJS 1> "list.txt"
```

And, once again without the leading spaces:

```bsh
@Set /A Levels = %~1 + 1
@(For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe . . /E /L /LEV:%LEVELS% /NC /NS /NFL /NJH /NJS 2^> NUL') Do @Echo %%G) 1> "list.txt"
```

*Please ensure, if this is for anything important, to check for a valid input argument first.*

Comment: this is awesome! doesn't answer my question of weird behaviour during recursive calls, but does the job perfectly and so much faster! i readjusted the argument handling and robocopy source to "." to use the script right from the containing directory but this is just flavour. thank you very much!

Comment: edit is again very elegant. btw, i figured out /xd .* omits hidden folders like .git, if that is of matter to anyone reaching this question.